# linq2twitter format date issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I would like to have the date printed out like "Created 2 Days Ago" or "Created 18 hours ago" - But im kindda stuck on how to do this, that I got so far is:

Basicly I want to get the datetime printet out as Twitter does itself in their website

```
public class TweetModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set;  }

    public TweetModel(Status status)
    {
        Timestamp = (DateTime.Now - status.CreatedAt).TotalDays.ToString();
        Username = status.User.ScreenNameResponse;
        Message = FormatTweet(status);
    }
    protected string FormatTweet(Status status)
    {
        var entities = new List<EntityBase>();
        entities.AddRange(status.Entities.HashTagEntities);
        entities.AddRange(status.Entities.UrlEntities);
        entities.AddRange(status.Entities.UserMentionEntities);
        entities = entities.OrderByDescending(item => item.Start).ToList();
        var linkedText = status.Text;
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (entity is HashTagEntity)
            {
                var tagEntity = (HashTagEntity)entity;
                linkedText = string.Format(
                    "{0}<a class=\"tweetlink\" href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23{1}\">#{1}</a>{2}",
                    linkedText.Substring(0, entity.Start),
                    tagEntity.Tag,
                    linkedText.Substring(entity.End));
            }
            else if (entity is UserMentionEntity)
            {
                var mentionEntity = (UserMentionEntity)entity;

                linkedText = string.Format(
                    "{0}<a class=\"tweetlink\" href=\"http://twitter.com/{1}\">@{1}</a>{2}",
                    linkedText.Substring(0, entity.Start),
                    mentionEntity.ScreenName,
                    linkedText.Substring(entity.End));
            }
            else if (entity is UrlEntity)
            {
                var urlEntity = (UrlEntity)entity;
                linkedText = string.Format(
                    "{0}<a class=\"tweetlink\" href=\"{1}\">{1}</a>{2}",
                    linkedText.Substring(0, entity.Start),
                    urlEntity.Url,
                    linkedText.Substring(entity.End));
            }
        }
        return linkedText;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by doing the following:

```
public class TweetModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set;  }

    public TweetModel(Status status)
    {
        Timestamp = ToAgo(status);
        Username = status.User.ScreenNameResponse;
        Message = FormatTweet(status);
    }

    public static string ToAgo(Status status)
     {
         DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
         DateTime date2 = status.CreatedAt;
         if (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) >= 0)
         {
             TimeSpan ts = date1.Subtract(date2);
             if (ts.TotalDays >= 1)
                return string.Format("{0} dage", (int)ts.TotalDays);
            else if (ts.Hours > 2)
                return string.Format("{0} timer", ts.Hours);
            else if (ts.Hours > 0)
                return string.Format("{0} timer, {1} minutes", 
                       ts.Hours, ts.Minutes);
            else if (ts.Minutes > 5)
                return string.Format("{0} minutter", ts.Minutes);
            else if (ts.Minutes > 0)
                return string.Format("{0} minutter, {1} sekunder", 
                       ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
            else
                return string.Format("{0} sekunder", ts.Seconds);
        }
        else
            return "Not valid";
    }

    protected string FormatTweet(Status status)
    {
        var entities = new List<EntityBase>();
        entities.AddRange(status.Entities.HashTagEntities);
        entities.AddRange(status.Entities.UrlEntities);
        entities.AddRange(status.Entities.UserMentionEntities);
        entities = entities.OrderByDescending(item => item.Start).ToList();
        var linkedText = status.Text;
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (entity is HashTagEntity)
            {
                var tagEntity = (HashTagEntity)entity;
                linkedText = string.Format(
                    "{0}<a class=\"tweetlink\" href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23{1}\">#{1}</a>{2}",
                    linkedText.Substring(0, entity.Start),
                    tagEntity.Tag,
                    linkedText.Substring(entity.End));
            }
            else if (entity is UserMentionEntity)
            {
                var mentionEntity = (UserMentionEntity)entity;

                linkedText = string.Format(
                    "{0}<a class=\"tweetlink\" href=\"http://twitter.com/{1}\">@{1}</a>{2}",
                    linkedText.Substring(0, entity.Start),
                    mentionEntity.ScreenName,
                    linkedText.Substring(entity.End));
            }
            else if (entity is UrlEntity)
            {
                var urlEntity = (UrlEntity)entity;
                linkedText = string.Format(
                    "{0}<a class=\"tweetlink\" href=\"{1}\">{1}</a>{2}",
                    linkedText.Substring(0, entity.Start),
                    urlEntity.Url,
                    linkedText.Substring(entity.End));
            }
        }
        return linkedText;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more on the status and the EntityBase? Your FormatTweet method doesn't seem to return the actual tweet but the Screen name and date. Correct me if I'm wrong.

You have defined:

var linkedText = status.Text

But you are overwriting linkedText in the for loop. If this is intended then it is fine otherwise use string.concat to concatenate linkedText.